# Why no one / few people use abstractions? (Repository/DAO implementations)

Tags: database, repository-pattern, dao, abstraction

I've read this article about Repositories over DAO and I've seen several implementations of DAO but I'm just wondering why no one abstracts the use of these patterns. For instance, in the article, the author uses AccountRepository instead of a generic Repository.

```
public class DatabaseRepository<T> {

    public boolean addItem(T item);
    public int removeItem(int id);
    public int updateItem(int id, T item);
    public List<T> query(Specification<T> specification);

}
```

Is this sort of implementation bad? I don't have an in-depth experience regarding actual software engineering standards so I'm sure I might be missing a certain point or flaw here.

Comment: This is the article if anyone is interested: https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/

Answer (score 0):

The biggest reason is because when you have DatabaseRepository, everything has to be generic. When you have AccountRepository, you can have methods inside the repository that are very specific to only Accounts.

I think where you may trip up on is because you have a method called Query that will return essentially anything you want. Personally, I request my team not to do this and instead encapsulate any query logic inside the repository itself (Of course if DatabaseRepository is an abstract class this is OK). The main reason for this is reusability. It's usually pretty likely that a particular query will be used by more than one piece of code.

Comment: But what if I have several other classes that also use Repository methods? Doesn't it make sense to implement Repository _then_ declare specific methods?

Comment: Yes exactly! Maybe I wasn't clear but AccountRepository should inherit from DatabaseRepository. So AccountRepository:DatabaseRepository<Account>. 

Then you have generic methods that are shared across all repositories, and specifics in that particular repository.